# Twitter4j and authenticating to Twitter

Tags: java, twitter, stream, twitter4j

For the moment I'm just trying to get up a simple driver in Java to hook into the Twitter streaming API and gather some tweets. But the sample code provided on the twitter4j site doesn't work and it provides little direction as to how to properly authenticate to Twitter.

For now this is what I have (literally copied from the site):

http://pastebin.com/7udeFT9i

I did it programmatically this time, but obviously it doesn't authenticate with nothing but *'s. But I'm not sure what values to put into the ConfigurationBuilder. I've seen some that have hardcoded values and others that call a getter from a Twitter instance, but in general I'm just not sure what Twitter needs for me to be able to access the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scribe -

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Comment: Please see my other response - my issue is not with implementing the authorization code; it's with getting the ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret.

Comment: First login to your twitter account.
Go to url https://dev.twitter.com/apps
Click to "Create new application".
Fill the fields and you will get consumer key and secrete key.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use OAuth to access twitter programmaticly. You should start with the Twitter OAuth docs:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Comment: I should have been clearer when I was posing my question: I'm aware that I need to use OAuth. However, I don't know where to get the keys, and none of the documentation makes that clear.